# Problem with paging for specific users (not admin users) in document library view

Tags: web-part, document, view, library

I have a document library inserted within a web part in a page and the problem is that specific users (not admin users) cannot go to page #2 to view its documents.
the filters do not work either.
if Admin users are logged this elements can be displayed and filters work fine.
With other user logged cannot be displayed.

Best Regards
Jorge

[image]

[image]